# layer div at center of a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to implements like in the image and I have done everything except the loader part.
when I click on the checkbox on the left , I want `div(loade+text "updating results)` come at the center of the search results div.

NOTE:

1. Even if scroll bar is there , still `div(loade+text "updating results)` is coming at center.
2. `div(loade+text "updating results)` is not coming in center of page , rather coming on center of search resuls (exclude left checkbox are).

please help to make this loader at center of search results

** the image I attached is desired, I have not implement it.

[image: I need to implements]

Comment: Please show us what did you tried so far

Comment: Show up your Code please. However, to do so, you need to use jQuery `Load()` function. And, need to create a container wrapper for your search results area. So, whenever you make any checkbox, it will fire `$.ajax` request to your `APi, WebService` and generates the html there. And then, load that html to your container by `$('myContainerResults').load('/data/results.php');` or etc.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you know what you want ?

> i want div(loade+text "updating results) come at the center of the
>   search results
>
> is not coming in center of page , rather coming on center of search
>   resuls

I'll assume you want the "updating results" div in the center of the screen.

You need to set it's position to fixed to keep it out of the document flow, then set the position to 50% from both the top and the left, finally adjust the margins to half of the elements size to take account for the element.

```
#updating_results_divs_id {
    position: fixed;
    height: 200px;
    width: 400px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -100px;
    margin-left: -200px;
}
```

Comment: ** the image i attached is desired, i have not implement it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the loading `div` should be positioned `absolute`, and if you make it nested inside the search result `div`, try to add this style:

```
{
    left: 50%; 
    top:50%
}
```

Comment: but how will it handle when there will be scroll bar

Answer (score 0):

You may tru jQuery **[BlockUI](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/block/)** plugin. **[Here](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/block/#demos)** are some demos. You can go through the CSS used there as well.

Also, you may have a look at **[Dead Center](http://www.wpdfd.com/editorial/thebox/deadcentre4.html)**

Comment: i m aware of this plugin.
by using this whole page will become not-click-able  rather a div.
i know how to solve this but don't know how to centrally align it.

Answer (score 0):

```
    leftPos = $('.searchResultsDiv').offset().left +($('.searchResultsDiv').width() - $('.layerDiv').width())/2;
    topPos = $('.searchResultsDiv').offset().top + ($(window).height()-$('.layerDiv').height())/5;
    $('.layerDiv')
        .css('position','fixed')
        .css('left',leftPos)
        .css('top',topPos);
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this might help someone in the future:

```
function setToCenterOfParent( obj, parentObj ) {
    var height = $( obj ).height();
    var width = $( obj ).width();
    if ( parentObj == window ) {
        $( obj ).css( 'top', ( $( parentObj ).height() / 2 ) - ( height / 2 ) );
        $( obj ).css( 'left', ( $( parentObj ).width() / 2 ) - ( width / 2 ) );
    }
    else {
        $( obj ).css( 'top', ( $( parentObj ).height() / 2 ) - ( height / 2 ) + $( parentObj ).position().top );
        $( obj ).css( 'left', ( $( parentObj ).width() / 2 ) - ( width / 2 ) + $( parentObj ).position().left );
    }
}
```